# Encrypt and decrypt querystring in ColdFusion - parsing resultant string for parameters and values

Tags: parsing, coldfusion, query-string, encryption

I'm sure this is quite simple but I can't seem to get it right

In ColdFusionI've encrypted a querystring and then decrypted the `CGI.Query_String` value easily enough. I then have a single string which looks like a querystring. But I need to reference the querystring values as I would normally using `URL.` notation (for example). 
How do I do this?

I've tried the code below but can't seem to parse the values out of the structure:

```
<cfscript>
    myStruct = structNew();
    for(i=1; i LTE listLen(decrypted,'&');i=i+1) {
        structInsert(myStruct, i, listGetAt(decrypted,i,'&'));
    }
</cfscript>
```

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE: (More info if I wasn't clear)**

I'm sending data via `CFLOCATION` with an encrypted querystring. Just to hide some irrelevant info from the user.  What I want to do is use the querystring information after it has been decrypted. But I can no longer use the ColdFusion `URL` structure. So I'm asking how do I parse the information from the decrypted string so I can use it (e.g. within a where clause of a SQL query or simply just display on the page).

Say my decrypted string is `update=0&balance=1145.00`

How do I go about using something like `<cfoutput>#update#</cfoutput>`?

Comment: Maybe its just monday morning, but I have no clue what you are asking.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Hi, I updated above, to (hopefully) add more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `str` is your querystring:

```
<CFSET str = "asdf=1&asd&as=3" />

<CFSET mystruct = structnew() />
<CFLOOP list="#str#" delimiters="&" index="i">
    <CFSET key = listfirst(i,"=") />
    <CFIF listlen(i,"=") GT 1>
        <CFSET value = listlast(i,"=") />
    <CFELSE>
        <CFSET value = "" />
    </CFIF>
    <CFSET mystruct[key] = value />
</CFLOOP>
```

Comment: and as an example the values can be used in the following way if anyone's wondering `<cfoutput>#mystruct.asdf#</cfoutput>`